# Not able to show my own message on beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I want to show an alert if user has entered a qty in a input field on the page for adding a product but instead of adding it to the cart clicks on some other action. In that case I want user to confirm his action. 
But returning a string from the handler function for `onbeforeunload` is having no effect on the alert shown by both chrome(version 53.0.2785.89 (64-bit)) and firefox(version 48) on Ubuntu.

Code is below:

```
<script>

    (function($){

        var confirmOnPageExit = function (e){
            // If we haven't been passed the event get the window.event
            e = e || window.event;

            var message = 'Are you sure you don\'t want to add these item(s) to cart?';

            // For IE6-8 and Firefox prior to version 4
            if (e) 
            {
                e.returnValue = message;
            }

            // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
            return message;
        };

        function isAnyInputHasValue(){

            var hasSomeQty = false;    
            var qtyInputs = $('input.qty');            

            if(qtyInputs.length > 0){
                qtyInputs.each(function(){
                    if($(this).val().length > 0){
                        hasSomeQty = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } 

            return hasSomeQty;   
        }


        $(document).ready(function(){

            var shouldConfirm = isAnyInputHasValue(); 
            if(shouldConfirm){
                window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit;
                //$(window).on('beforeunload', confirmOnPageExit);
            }else{
                window.onbeforeunload = '';
            }

            console.log('on page load ', shouldConfirm);    

        });



        $(document).on('change', 'input.qty', function(){

            var shouldConfirm = false;

            if($(this).val().length > 0){
                shouldConfirm = true;
            }else{
                shouldConfirm = isAnyInputHasValue();
            }

            if(shouldConfirm){
                window.onbeforeunload = confirmOnPageExit;
            }else{
                window.onbeforeunload = '';
            }

            console.log('on qty change ', shouldConfirm);

        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Same code seems to work for others who previously asked same question on stackoverflow. Also tried to use jQuery `.on` method to subscribe to `onbeforeunload` event with no success.

I have prepared a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/zc08faoy/1/

Comment: It displays a popup box when I attempt to unload the page - if I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it should display a alert with message saying "Are you sure you don't want to add these item(s) to cart?"

Comment: Chrome (v.51) has removed custom message support: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480  or see @Dekel link for browser support

Comment: @A.Wolff, thanks :) you are more than welcome to upvote the answer there ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for pasting the status link here. I was not sure that it was available to previous versions but not to new ones.

Comment: @Dekel, Thanks for the explanation in other answer. May be you can add this detail too.

Comment: @div, added links in the bottom of the answer. Thanks!